# Is there a way to overload << to do a no-op on a certain class specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

My class `N` takes a type `T` and a varying amount of types `F...`

What's really happening is that I am overloading `operator()` to take a function reference and the arguments that that function will be supplied. It's like a bind function. But when the function reference returns `void`, I don't want to be able to `std::cout` the value of that function call from `operator()`. So I added an overload of `operator<<` for `std::cout` to NOT do anything when the return-type of the function reference is `void` but I guess I'm not writing out the function signature correctly because I get errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct N;

template <typename T, typename ... F>
struct N<T(F...)> {
    T operator()(T (&t)(F...), F &&... f) {
        return t(std::forward<F>(f)...);
    }
};

template <typename ... T>
void operator<< (std::ostream &, const N<void(T...)> &) {}
                                 // don't do anything when void

void f(int, int) {}

int main() {

    N<void(int, int)> bind;

    std::cout << bind(f, 5, 4); // errors

}
```

The errors that I'm getting are very long, so I won't post them; they are typical error messages for printing on a function returning `void`.

The above code fails because I'm printing out a function that returns `void`; and that is the function `f`. My overload of `operator<<` doesn't seem to be affecting anything. What am I doing wrong here? If you need any more detail just say so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are explicitly calling `operator()` on the object `bind`.  (Btw, don't use the name `bind` for that object, `std::bind` is overly famous and it will confuse people)

The code does what you asked it to do.  It called the functor.  Which returned `void`.

Nothing in your `operator<<` overload has any impact at all on that functor being called.

Now that it is called, we see we have a `std::cout << void` -- which also has absolutely nothing to do with your `operator<<`.

Replace `std::cout << bind(f, 5, 4); // errors` with `std::cout << bind;` and your overloaded `operator<<` will be invoked.

The order of operations in C++ is not left-to-right.  `a << b(c)` first evaluates `tmp=b(c)`, then evaluates `a << tmp`.

Now, an example of how you could handle this problem would be to specialize your `N` type to, when it returns a `void`, to instead return a `pseudo_void`.  `pseudo_void` blocks all use, except you have a `<<` overload that just consists of `return os;`  (oh, and `operator<<( ostream& os, blah )` should always return `os`).

This can cause other problems.  As an example, you'll want a "get rid of pseudo-void" traits classes and the like.  But it gives you the syntax you want.

Comment: I don't understand how I would implement this `psuedo_void` trait. Have any ideas?

Comment: What part?  If you are passed a function signature returning void, instead return `pseudo_void`.  That is easy.  Then have some method of exposing an version that really does return void, just in case other template code needs you not to lie.  Specialize `operator<<` to take `pseudo_void` and not output anything.  Each step is rather separate.

Comment: You say to return `pseudo_void` but what *is* it? Is it a typedef? A variable? And I don't know how to specialize `operator<<` that way (sorry I'm new to template-MP)..

Comment: `struct pseudo_void { };` would do.  Just a placeholder for void return types that you can overload `<<` on to do nothing.  Make it so an instance of pseudo void outputs nothing.

Comment: Yes! [I finally got it!](http://ideone.com/6I25xr#view_edit_box) Thanks for your help :)